# non naive version of Looman -Menchof

Tags: complex-analysis

Complex numbers newbie here.
Want to show that $$f(z)= \frac{z^5}{|z|^4}$$ if $z \neq 0$ and $0$ when $z=0$ is not complex differentiable at 0. This function satisfies CR. Is there an elegant way of doing showing that it is not complex differentiable?

Comment: Use the definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall:

> $f(z)$ is differentiable at $z_0$ if  the limit
> $$\lim_{z \to z_0} \frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}$$
> exists.

If you want to show that $f(z)$ is differentiable at $0$, then we need to look at
$$\lim_{z \to 0} \frac{f(z)-f(0)}{z-0}=\lim_{z \to 0} \frac{\frac{z^5}{|z|^4}}{z} = \lim_{z \to 0} \frac{z^4}{|z|^4}.$$
And the limit above does not exist. Why? The limits from two different paths are different. More precisely,

Case 1: $z \to 0$ along a real axis, that is, $z=(x,y)=(x,0)$.

In this case, $$\lim_{z \to 0} \frac{z^4}{|z|^4} = \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x^4}{x^4}=1.$$

Case 2: $z \to 0$ along a line $y=2x$, that is, $z = (x,2x)$.

You can see that
$$\lim_{z \to 0} \frac{z^4}{|z|^4} = \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{(x+2xi)^4}{|x+2xi|^4}=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x^4 (1+2i)^4}{x^4 \sqrt{5}^4} = \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{(1+2i)^4}{25} =\frac{-7-24i}{25}\neq 1.$$

Two limits from case 1 and case2 are different, and so the limit
$$\lim_{z \to 0} \frac{f(z)-f(0)}{z-0}$$
does not exist. This implies that $f'(0)$ does not exist, and so $f$ is not differentiable at $0$.

Comment: Is there a way to show CR holds without brute force?